When I call the same modal screen twice (JSF) it doesn't work very well
I have a surreal problem. I have an xhtml (JSF) that has two buttons calling the same modal for different fields (pnlDadosUsuario, first and pnlDadosUsuarioVinculado, second). Both times the modal displays the list of Users correctly and returns the correctly selected user. The problem is that on the first call the sorting and filtering do not work. Can someone help me?
Main Screen
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:m="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
    template="/template/ui.xhtml">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <ui:define name="body">
        <p:panel>
            <h:outputText value="Responsável Eletrônico" styleClass="header_pagina" />
            <h:form id="form-geral">
                <br />
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="4" id="pnlDadosUsuario">
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <p:inputText id="txtUsuario" value="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.entidade.usuario.nome}" disabled="true" required="true" />
                                <p:watermark for="txtUsuario" value="Selecione um usuário" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandButton ajax="true" immediate="true" oncomplete="dlg.show();" icon="ui-icon-search"></p:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="4" id="pnlDadosUsuarioVinculado">
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <p:inputText id="txtUsuarioVinculado" value="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.entidade.usuarioVinculado.nome}" disabled="true" required="true"/>
                                <p:watermark for="txtUsuarioVinculado" value="Selecione um responsável eletrônico" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandButton ajax="true" immediate="true" oncomplete="dlgUsuarioVinculado.show()" icon="ui-icon-search"></p:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
                <p:commandButton value="SALVAR" action="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.salvar}" update=":#{p:component('tabela')}" />
            </h:form>

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable id="tabela" value="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.listaTodos}" var="ent" sortMode="multiple" emptyMessage="Nenhum Registro Encontrado" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" >
                    <p:column headerText="Usuário" sortBy="usuario.nome" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="usuario.nome">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Usuário" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ent.usuario.nome}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Usuário" sortBy="usuario.nome" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="usuario.nome">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Responsável Eletrônico" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ent.usuarioVinculado.nome}" />
                    </p:column>
                    
                    <p:column headerText="Excluir">
                        <p:commandLink title="Excluir" onclick="confirmaExclusao.show();">
                            <p:graphicImage title="Somente o usuário criador e despachos sem movimentações podem ser removidos" value="/img/btn-excluir.png"></p:graphicImage>
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.entidade.id}" value="#{ent.id}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
            <h:form>
                <p:confirmDialog message="Deletar Vinculo" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" header="Confirmar" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmaExclusao" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true">
                    <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="confirmaExclusao.hide()" action="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.remover}" update=":#{p:component('tabela')}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Não" oncomplete="confirmaExclusao.hide()" action="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.limparEntidade}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:form>
            <h:form>
                <p:dialog modal="true" id="modalFormUsuario" widgetVar="dlg" header="Consultar Usuário" resizable="false" onHide="PF('tabelaWidgetVar').clearFilters();">
                    <ui:include src="/pagina/seguranca/componentes/pesquisa_usuario.xhtml">
                        <ui:param name="action" value="dlg.hide()" />
                        <ui:param name="reRender" value=":#{p:component('pnlDadosUsuario')}" />
                        <ui:param name="usuario" value="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.entidade.usuario}" />
                    </ui:include>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
            <h:form>
                <p:dialog modal="true" id="modalFormVinculado" widgetVar="dlgUsuarioVinculado" header="Consultar Usuário" resizable="false" onHide="PF('tabelaWidgetVar').clearFilters();">
                    <ui:include src="/pagina/seguranca/componentes/pesquisa_usuario.xhtml">
                        <ui:param name="action" value="dlgUsuarioVinculado.hide()" />
                        <ui:param name="reRender" value=":#{p:component('pnlDadosUsuarioVinculado')}" />
                        <ui:param name="usuario" value="#{responsavelEletronicoBean.entidade.usuarioVinculado}" />
                    </ui:include>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
        <br />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>


Modal screen
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <p:dataTable id="tabela" widgetVar="tabelaWidgetVar" styleClass="tabela" value="#{usuarioIlimitadaBean.listaEntidadeInternos}" filteredValue="#{usuarioIlimitadaBean.listaEntidadeFiltered}" var="ent" sortMode="multiple" emptyMessage="Nenhum Registro Encontrado" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
    <p:column headerText="CPF/CNPJ" sortBy="#{ent.cpfCnpj}" filterBy="#{ent.cpfCnpj}" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="CPF/CNPJ" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{ent.cpfCnpj}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Matrícula" sortBy="#{ent.matricula}" filterBy="#{ent.matricula}" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Matrícula" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{ent.matricula}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{ent.nomeStatus}" filterBy="#{ent.nomeStatus}" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Nome" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{ent.nomeStatus}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Tipo Usuário" sortBy="#{ent.tipoUsuario}">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Tipo Usuário" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{ent.tipoUsuario}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column exportable="false">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Controle" />
      </f:facet>
      <p:commandButton title="Confirmar" oncomplete="#{action}" update="#{reRender}" icon="ui-icon-check" process="@this">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{usuario}" value="#{ent}" />
      </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>


</ui:composition>

Bean
package seguranca.bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;
import com.lowagie.text.BadElementException;
import com.lowagie.text.Chunk;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;

import core.util.EmailValidator;
import core.util.Funcoes;
import gerais.enumeration.TipoPessoa;
import gerais.enumeration.TipoUsuario;
import gerais.negocio.CargoFuncaoNegocio;
import gerais.negocio.LotacaoUsuarioNegocio;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import seguranca.entity.Usuario;
import seguranca.negocio.UsuarioNegocio;

@Slf4j
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
public class UsuarioIlimitadaBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -871294836219039397L;
    /**
     *
     */

    Usuario entidade = new Usuario();
    @Inject
    UsuarioNegocio usuarioNegocio;
    @Inject
    CargoFuncaoNegocio cargoFuncaoNegocio;
    @Inject
    LotacaoUsuarioNegocio lotacaoUsuarioNegocio;

    List<Usuario> listaEntidade = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    List<Usuario> listaEntidadeInternos = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    List<Usuario> listaEntidadeFiltered = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    List<Usuario> listaEntidadeInternosFiltered = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void iniciarTela() {
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            carregarPagina();
        }
    }

    private void carregarPagina() {
        try {
            listaEntidadeInternos = usuarioNegocio.getListaUsuariosInternos();
            listaEntidadeFiltered = listaEntidadeInternos;            
            //listaEntidade = usuarioNegocio.getListaUsuariosInternos();
            //listaEntidadeFiltered = listaEntidade;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Funcoes.adicionarMsg(e.getMessage(), true, e);
        }
    }

    public String getNomeBotao() {
        if (entidade.getId() > 0) {
            return "Editar Usuario";
        } else {
            return "Salvar Usuario";
        }
    }

    public String limparEntidade() {
        entidade = new Usuario();
        return null;
    }

    public void carregarLotacoesUsuarios(Usuario usuario) {
      try {
        this.entidade = usuario;
        this.entidade.setLotacoes(lotacaoUsuarioNegocio.getListaLotacaoUsuario(usuario.getId()));
        this.entidade.setLotacoesChefe(lotacaoUsuarioNegocio.getListaLotacaoUsuarioChefe(usuario.getId()));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Erro carregarLotacoesUsuarios", e);
        Funcoes.adicionarMsg(e.getMessage(), true);
      }
    }

    public String salvarUsuario() {
        try {
            prepararUsuario();

            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(entidade.getEmail()) && !EmailValidator.isValid(entidade.getEmail())){
                throw new Exception("E-mail informado é inválido!");
            }

            usuarioNegocio.salvarUsuario(entidade);
            Funcoes.adicionarMsg("Usuário cadastrado com sucesso", false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Funcoes.adicionarMsg(e.getMessage(), true, e);
        }
        carregarPagina();
        entidade = new Usuario();
        return null;
    }

    private void prepararUsuario() throws Exception {
        if (entidade.getTipoUsuario().equals(TipoUsuario.INTERNO)) {
            prepararUsuarioInterno();
        } else {
            prepararUsuarioExterno();
        }
    }

    private void prepararUsuarioExterno() {
        if (entidade.getTipoPessoa().equals(TipoPessoa.PESSOA_FISICA)) {
            entidade.setCnpj(null);
        } else if (entidade.getTipoPessoa().equals(TipoPessoa.PESSOA_JURIDICA)) {
            entidade.setCpf(null);
        }
        entidade.setMatricula(null);
        entidade.setLogin(null);
        entidade.setSenha(null);
        entidade.setTipoFuncionario(null);
        entidade.setAtivado(true);
    }

    private void prepararUsuarioInterno() throws Exception {
        entidade.setContato(null);
        entidade.setCnpj(null);
        entidade.setTipoPessoa(null);
    }

    public String excluirUsuario() {
        if (entidade.getId() > 0) {
            try {
                usuarioNegocio.deletarUsuario(entidade);
                Funcoes.adicionarMsg("Usuario deletado com sucesso", false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (Funcoes.isConstraintViolationException(e)) {
                    Funcoes.adicionarMsg("Não é possivel remover o Usuário, pois existem registros vinculados", true);
                } else {
                    Funcoes.adicionarMsg(e.getMessage(), true, e);
                }
            }
        }
        carregarPagina();
        entidade = new Usuario();
        return null;
    }

    public void preProcessPDF(Object document) throws IOException, BadElementException, DocumentException {
        Document pdf = (Document) document;
        pdf.open();
        pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        Font font = new Font();
        font.setSize(16);
        font.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Lista de Usuario", font));
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph.setSpacingAfter(30);
        pdf.add(paragraph);
    }

    public List<Usuario> autoComplete(String query) {
        List<Usuario> usuariosFiltrados = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        try {
            List<Usuario> todosUsuarios = usuarioNegocio.getListaTodosUsuarios();

            for (Usuario usuario : todosUsuarios) {
                if (usuario.getNome().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                    usuariosFiltrados.add(usuario);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return usuariosFiltrados;
    }

    /**** METODOS DE VALIDAÇÃO ***/

    public void validarDescricao(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (usuarioNegocio.existeRegistroPorAtributo("descricao", value, entidade.getId())) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Validação", "Banco com essa descrição já existe"));
        }
    }

    public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp, Object value) {
        String email = (String) value;

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(email) && !EmailValidator.isValid(email)) {
            ((UIInput) comp).setValid(false);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Validação", "E-mail informado é inválido");
            context.addMessage(comp.getClientId(context), message);
        }
    }

    /**** GETS E SETS DAS PROPRIEDADE ***/
    public List<Usuario> getListaEntidade() {
        return listaEntidade;
    }
    
    public List<Usuario> getListaEntidadeInternos(){
        return listaEntidadeInternos.stream()
                .filter(u-> u.getAtivado() && TipoUsuario.INTERNO.equals(u.getTipoUsuario())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    public List<Usuario> getListaEntidadeInternosFiltered(){
        return listaEntidadeInternos.stream().filter(u-> u.getAtivado() && TipoUsuario.INTERNO.equals(u.getTipoUsuario())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    public List<Usuario> getListaEntidadeInternosExternos(){
        return listaEntidade.stream()
                            .filter(u -> u.getAtivado() && (TipoUsuario.INTERNO.equals(u.getTipoUsuario()) || TipoUsuario.EXTERNO.equals(u.getTipoUsuario())))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void setEntidade(Usuario entidade) {
        this.entidade = entidade;
    }

    public Usuario getEntidade() {
        return entidade;
    }

    public UsuarioNegocio getUsuarioNegocio() {
        return usuarioNegocio;
    }

    public void setUsuarioNegocio(UsuarioNegocio usuarioNegocio) {
        this.usuarioNegocio = usuarioNegocio;
    }

    public List<Usuario> getListaEntidadeFiltered() {
        return listaEntidadeFiltered;
    }

    public void setListaEntidadeFiltered(List<Usuario> listaEntidadeFiltered) {
        this.listaEntidadeFiltered = listaEntidadeFiltered;
    }

}





Can you create a PrimeFaces Test reproducer: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test  Its impossible to debug your issue from code snippets.
